# Properties to configure for spring-cloud-dataflow-rest-client when using Azure AD to secure spring cloud dataflow server

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to use the spring-cloud-dataflow-rest-client v2.6.0 in an application to launch spring cloud tasks. I followed the instructions on this page https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-identity-provider-azure to secure Spring-cloud-dataflow-server using Azure AD. However, I am unable to get the setup that was provided for dataflow-shell to work with the SCDF rest client. I know shell internally uses SCDF-rest-client. So, not sure why it won't work for me.

Which properties should I use if my application which uses SCDF-rest-client is to launch tasks like the shell?

I tried with the following properties but I keep getting an invalid scope error.

```
-Dspring.cloud.dataflow.client.authentication.client-id=yhas7wqh-2a5d-4795-babb-b6213f896b52
-Dspring.cloud.dataflow.client.authentication.client-secret=asjajd8hhsasajdassakja
-Dspring.cloud.dataflow.client.authentication.oauth2.client-registration-id=Batch-Launcher
-Dspring.cloud.dataflow.client.authentication.token-uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/d8bb2fd3-e835-4d68-b9db-7402a9bf39f1/oauth2/v2.0/token
-Dspring.cloud.dataflow.client.authentication.scope=api://dataflow-server/dataflow.deploy,api://dataflow-server/dataflow.view,offline_access
-Dspring.cloud.dataflow.client.authentication.oauth2.username=abcddemo@afdemo12.onmicrosoft.com
-Dspring.cloud.dataflow.client.authentication.oauth2.password=abcdPwd
-Dspring.cloud.dataflow.client.authentication.basic.username=abcddemo@afdemo12.onmicrosoft.com
-Dspring.cloud.dataflow.client.authentication.basic.password=abcdPwd
```

The exception that I get
Caused by: org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthorizationException: [invalid_scope] AADSTS70011: The provided request must include a 'scope' input parameter. The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope api://dataflow-server/dataflow.deploy offline_access is not valid.

Can someone from SCDF team update the Azure provider docs to include also how one can use SCDF rest client like shell to invoke SCDF API.

Comment: Which oauth2 flow is used by SCDF-rest-client? Is it client_credentials(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) or ROPC (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) flow.  I was able to get access token with CURL when using client_credentials flow and password flow but the application throws a 403 forbidden error. Not sure what is the issue with application properties